# PHP Datetime-local min and max

Tags: html

I have a datetime-local input. I'm trying to set an max and min values for it but it does not seem to work when testing. Any feedback would be appreciated.

Thanks

`<input type="datetime-local" min='2019-12-06 10:00:00' max='2020-12-31 20:00:00' class="form-control" name="date" id="date" />`

Comment: How is it not working for you? What results are you getting as opposed to desired results? Also, is this "php" related? I see no code for it.

Comment: Seconds are [not supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local)

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
 an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
 then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
 [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/),
 how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Sorry for not providing an output information. I've changed it so it looks like so.```<input type="datetime-local" min='2019-12-06 10:00' max='2020-12-31 20:00' class="form-control" name="date" id="date" />```. The output on the label still exceed the min or max that is setup. I can go to 2023-12-31 without any errors

Answer (score 0):

Try min and max value in this format `2019-12-05T01:00`

```
<input type="datetime-local" min='2019-12-06T10:00' max='2020-12-31T20:00' class="form-control" name="date" id="date" />
```

Comment: What I would like to see, in addition is a kind of snippets for validating web forms entries regarding dates. The entries should be also coded in PHP?

I have a web form which already has set up dynamically a «minimum date» which is 48 hours (2 days) AFTER the current day (“today”) and the “maximum date» is set to 3 months after the “minimum date”. It has a calendar widget too but belongs to HTML and the min and max were set up with JavaScript. And it has validation in front end.

Could I validate the entries of this calendar with PHP too? Or should I design another widget for PHP validat?

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck in a problem like this for some days. From @Ganeshkumar K 's answer I got an idea with PHP. Posting this here, if any newbie like me can get help from this in future.

As "datetime-local" only accepts values "2021-05-27T10:00" in this format, If we want to set the input time's minimum value is today and maximum value is 10 days from today, we can do this as follows:

**For minimum range:**
Assign today's date in $mindate using `date("Y-m-d")`
and today's time in $mintime using `date("h:i")`
Then Concatenate these two keeping "T" in middle using `$mindate."T".$mintime`

**For maximum range:**
Assign date of 10 days from today in $maxdate using `date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+10 Days"))`
and time in $maxtime using `date("h:i")`
Then Concatenate these two keeping "T" in middle using `$maxdate."T".$maxtime`

At last in HTML input set `min = "<?php echo$min?>"` and max = "`<?php echo $max?>"`

```html
<?php
$mindate = date("Y-m-d");
$mintime = date("h:i");
$min = $mindate."T".$mintime;
$maxdate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+10 Days"));
$maxtime = date("h:i");
$max = $maxdate."T".$maxtime;
?>
<input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" id="time" name="time" min="<?php echo $min?>" max="<?php echo $max?>" required>
```